# Homeomorphism theorem

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is 1-1 and $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces,  then if $\forall  A\subset X, f(\overline{A})=\overline{f(A)} $ then $f$ is homeomorphism.

1) Assume $f$ is 1-1 and $\forall  A\subset X, f(\overline{A})=\overline{f(A)} $. I need to show that f is a homeomorphism.

It is sufficient to show that f is continuous and $f^{-1}$ as well is continuous. I cannot show these steps unless f is onto since I need to use $f(f^{-1}(A))=A $ often.
Please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that $f[A]$ is open, when you specified nothing about the set $A$?

Comment: As Cameron Buie points out, $f$ is continuous iff $f(\overline A)\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$. The reverse inclusion $f(\overline A)\supseteq\overline{f(A)}$ is equivalent to $f$ being a closed map. And closed bijective maps are also open.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is bijective. Then there are a few useful things to note/prove:

> (1) $f$ is continuous if and only if $f\left(\overline{A}\right)\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$ for all $A\subseteq X$. In the same way, $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}\left(\overline{A}\right)\subseteq\overline{f^{-1}(A)}$ for all $A\subseteq Y$.
>
> (2) $f$ is an open map if and only if $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is continuous.
>
> (3) Given $A\subseteq X,B\subseteq Y$, we have $f(A)\subseteq B$ if and only if $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$.

Is that enough to get you started?

---

Now, let's suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is 1-to-1, but not necessarily onto. Putting $Z=f(X)$, we have $f:X\to Z$ is a bijection, and $f^{-1}:Z\to X$ is perfectly well-defined. Now, I'm going to give slightly altered versions of the above hints (and add another one) to fit your change to the question. First, though, I'm going to define the following notation to avoid confusion:

> Given a subset $S$ of a topological space $T$, we will now denote the *closure of $S$ in $T$* by $\text{cl}_T(S)$. (Since we're dealing with several different spaces, it's a good idea to keep track of where things are.)

Now, we want to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism *from $X$ to $Z$* (rather than to $Y$) if and only if $$\forall A\subseteq X,\:f\bigl(\text{cl}_X(A)\bigr)=\text{cl}_Y\bigl(f(A)\bigr).\tag{#}$$

Now, let's amend my list of useful notes/results-to-be-proved.

> (1) $f:X\to Z$ is continuous if and only if $f\bigl(\text{cl}_X(A)\bigr)\subseteq\text{cl}_Z\bigl(f(A)\bigr)$ for all $A\subseteq X.$ In the same way, $f^{-1}:Z\to X$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}\bigl(\text{cl}_Z(A)\bigr)\subseteq\text{cl}_X\bigl(f(A)\bigr)$ for all $A\subseteq Z.$
>
> (2) $f:X\to Z$ is an open map if and only if $f^{-1}:Z\to X$ is continuous.
>
> (3) Given $A\subseteq X,B\subseteq Y$, we have $f(A)\subseteq B$ if and only if $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$. (This is also true if we replace $Y$ with $Z.$)
>
> (4) $S\subseteq Z$ is closed in $Z$ if and only if there is some $F\subseteq Y$ such that $S=F\cap Z$ and $F$ is closed in $Y;$ thus, $\text{cl}_Z(S)=Z\cap\text{cl}_Y(S)$ for all $S\subseteq Z.$

Hopefully that will get you where you need to go.

Comment: @ Cameron Thank you for your input,can you help me showing that my function is onto? Thank you.

Comment: @Klara Your assumptions do not imply that $f$ is onto. Consider $X=\{0\}$ and $f(0)=y_0$ for some $y_0\in Y$. Actually, your function is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: @ Julien yes it does not imply that, but I thought all homeomorphisms are onto functions.

Comment: @Klara: If you only assume that the function is 1-to-1, then your hypothesis $$\forall A\subseteq X,\:f\left(\overline A\right)=\overline{f(A)}\tag{#}$$ isn't going to be enough. For example, let $Y$ be the real numbers in the usual topology, $X=\{0\}$, $f$ the inclusion $X\hookrightarrow Y$. Then $f$ is 1-to-1, and satisfies $(\#)$, but isn't a homeomorphism. You're going to *have* to assume that $f$ is onto, as well (as you were when I posted this answer). The best you can say without the onto assumption is that $f$ is an [imbedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imbedding#General_topology).

Comment: @ Cameron, The book does not mention it in the problem nor on the definition of homeomorphism- Haaser real analysis. I guess I will just assume it and see what my teacher says. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ cameron so you are saying that without the onto F^-1 is not even a function.

Comment: @Klara: Certainly not a function $Y\to X$. However, if we put $Z=f(X)$, then $f:X\to Z$ is bijective, and $f^{-1}:Z\to X$ is perfectly well-defined. I will alter my answer to fit with your altered question, shortly.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you.

Comment: @Klara: Quite all right. Take a look, and see what you can do.

Comment: @CameronBuie You stole my example and the remainder of my comment! Kidding of course.

Comment: @julien: Glad you're just kidding, and glad you took it upon yourself to help out. ^_^