# Example of a function that is continuous at $c$ whose inverse is discontinuous at $f(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I'd like an example of a function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ and a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that:

- $f$ is invertible.
- $f$ is continuous at $c$.
- $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous at $f(c)$.

---

**Motivation:** There is a calculus book that states the following.

> Let $f$ be an invertible function defined on an interval $I$. If $f$ is differentiable at $c\in I$ and $f'(c)\neq 0$, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(c)$.

In the proof, the continuity of $f^{-1}$ at $f(c)$ is essential. Usually, the said essential fact is an hypothesis (if the domain is not an interval) or it is implied by the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $c$ (if the domain is an interval). But in the said book, both hipothesis are missing and the fact is justified as follows:

> As $f$ is differentiable at $c$, $f$ is continuous at $c$. Therefore, $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(c)$.

I suspect continuity at $c$ does not imply continuity of the inverse at $f(c)$ due to the following facts:

1. It seems it is not a common result in analysis books.
2. In the usual proofs that the inverse of a continuos map (on an interval or on a compact set) is continous, in order to prove that the inverse is continuous at a given point, we need the continuity of $f$ in the whole domain.
3. In more recent editions of the said book, the statement was modified (now, it is supposed that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $c$, which implies what is needed).

However, I do not have a counterexample.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362592/counter-examples-of-homeomorphism

Comment: this is the one variable case, so if f is continuous its inverse is continuous too. Look this [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Inverse_Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Inverse_Theorem)

Comment: @AndrewZhang My question is different. I'm talkin about continuity at a single point of an interval. Thus, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ cannot be continuous (in the whole domain).

Comment: @tac I'm not talking about continuous functions (in the entire interval). See my previous comment. Also, I referred to the linked result in item 2 of my question.

Comment: @mr_e_man The question is different (see my previous comments). Also, no answer gives a function continuous only at an interior point of its domain.

Comment: @tac: that's true if the domain is an interval. Consider $f(x)=x$ if $x\in[0,1)$ and $f(x)=x-1$ if $x\in[2,3)$.

Comment: @Taladris Not even. That's true if $f$ is *continuous on an interval*. But it can be defined on an interval and continuous at just one point. See my answer

Comment: Let $f(x)=x \vert x \vert$.  Then $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$ but $f^{-1}$ is not.

Comment: @RobertShore In the original post, I wrote "differentiability" where I should have written "continuity" (so the question in the middle was different from the question at the top). Now, I corrected it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example of such a function.
It comes from the book *Les contre-exemples en mathématiques* by Bertrand Hauchecorne (more precisely, section 8.22, page 150, in the second edition).

Consider $g\colon \Bbb R_+ \to \Bbb R_+$ defined by
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2} & \text{if} \quad x=n \quad \text{is an even integer},\\
\frac{1}{n+2} & \text{if} \quad x=n \quad \text{is an odd integer},\\
\frac{1}{2(n-1)} & \text{if} \quad x=\frac{1}{n} \quad \text{with} \quad n \geqslant 2 \quad \text{integer},\\
x & \text{in any other case}. 
\end{cases}
$$
Now, consider $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) & \text{if} \quad x \geqslant 0,\\
-g(-x) & \text{if} \quad x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
One shows with a bit of effort that $f$ is a bijection.

Note that $|f(x)| \leqslant |x|$ for all $x$, so that $f$ is continuous at $0$ with $f(0)=0$.
However, for all $n \geqslant 1$, $f(2n-1) = \frac{1}{2n+1}$ shows that $f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) = 2n-1 \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty$, so that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Amazing source.

Comment: @Pedro I was advised to read this book while I was in my first or second year as a student, and that's one of the best advices I've been given ever since.

Comment: (+1) Et est-ce qu'il existe un contre-exemple avec en plus $f'(0)$ existe et $\ne0?$

Comment: @AnneBauval Très bonne question. À cette heure-ci, je ne saurais répondre

Comment: Great answer, from a great book

Comment: @AnneBauval: Oui ! See the answer that I've posted.

Comment: @Didier Sounds like a really wise advice. Unfortunately, I was not told that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bijection $f$ from the interval $(-2,2)$ to the interval $(-\frac32,\frac32)$, such that $f$ is continuous at $0$, and in fact even differentiable there with $f'(0)=1$, but $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous at $f(0)=0$.

Define $f$ on the interval $(-1,1)$ by
$$
f(0) = 0
$$
and
$$
f(x) = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) x
,\quad\text{for}\quad
\frac{1}{n} \le |x| < \frac{1}{n-1}
\quad (n = 2,3,\dots)
.
$$
For $1 \le |x| < 2$, define $f$ in a piecewise linear way, such that it assumes precisely those values that it previously jumped over, as indicated by this picture:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. The picture is illuminating.

Comment: What a nice example!